# Sorting array unknown values in php

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I'd like to sort an array by every elements second value.
Like this example below. The values are unknown.

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    int(2)
    [1]=>
    int(1)                              **last in array**
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    int(7)
    [1]=>
    int(4)                              **first in array**
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    int(5)
    [1]=>
    int(2)                              **Second in array**
  }
}
```

Comment: `usort($myArray, function($a, $b) { return $a[1] <=> $b[1]; });` (PHP7) For earlier versions of PHP, you'll have to modify the callback function, but the [usort() docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) give you plenty of examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`usort` function should do the job:

```
$arr = [
    [2, 1],
    [7, 4],
    [5, 2],
];

usort($arr, function($a, $b){
   return $a[1] - $b[1];
});

print_r($arr);
```

The output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 5
            [1] => 2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 7
            [1] => 4
        )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution inspired from [here](https://www.codepunker.com/blog/3-solutions-for-multidimensional-array-sorting-by-child-keys-or-values-in-PHP)

```
$input = array(array(2,1),array(7,4),array(5,2));
function method1($a,$b) 
{
   return ($a[1] <= $b[1]) ? 1 : -1;
}
usort($input, "method1");
print_r($input);
```